# Reformulating to locate the second largest decision variable of a set of decision variables

Tags: optimization, modeling, indicator-constraints, reformulation-linearization

Consider a set of $A_{vn}$ decision variables such that $A_{v1},A_{v2},\cdots,A_{vn}<A$. While this is the standard formulation finding the maximum value of $A_{vn}$, I would also like to find the second largest $A_{vn}$ of this set of decision variables.

Comment: Are the $n$ values known to be distinct? If not, what is the desired behavior if there is a tie for largest?

Comment: Yes and no unfortunately, of all of them, only either one or two of them are to be non-zero, i.e., the others are to be zero. Additionally, all of them are integers that are to be greater or equal to zero. Lastly, the two non-zero variables might also be equal, though they should be unequal most of the time. Sorry for the initial omission of such information. Thank you!

Comment: Then just take the sum of all of them and subtract the largest.

Comment: Dear Dr Rob, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the second largest variable when all are nonnegative and at most two can be nonzero, just take the sum of all of them and subtract the largest.